# Using error_reporting(0); in an if statement?

Tags: php

I put this at the top of all my PHP files to prevent any errors from being displayed to visitors:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Is there any way to create an `if statement` so if an error does occur, I can have it email me, send a text, add it to the database, etc?

Basically I still want to completely disable error reporting so users don't see errors, but I also want to be notified of those errors occurring.  I don't need the code to perform the action (emailing, texting, etc).  I'm just trying to figure out what the `if statement` would be for it...

Comment: you can have error logging on, but display off

Comment: consult the official manuals on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error_handler in PHP per default. You CAN create a custom one and use set_error_handler("customError"); to make it do whatever you want.

Look at this page http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_error.asp

Regards